# how to get the session details from browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, session, browser

I want to know whether it's possible to get the session details of a particular website from the browser using javascript.

For example, I want to get the userid, name of the current user that is  logged into google from session details.

Any code examples or tuts will be appreciated.

Comment: but you have to log in to a website to have a session on that website ... you know your own name, right?

Comment: yes, sometimes instead of username we use email id for login....
but i think you got the general idea, i want user details

Comment: yes, so, you have to know how to log in to a site ... a site that you log in to usually has a profile page or some such where many details can be shown and edited - I simply must not understand your objectives, because I've never felt the need to use javascript to remember who I am

Comment: maybe what you call "session details" is different to what I understand "session details" are - how about an example of a site, the information you do know, and the session details you want to "retrieve" that you don't know

Comment: If you are looking to get the "current user who is logged into google" you cannot - Session is stored in a cookie, and cookies are only sent to domains specified by their owners (For good reason!). So the username/userid/any google data is only going to be sent to google domains, so you would not be able to read it on your site. You can test this if you visit your page and type in `document.cookie`, it will be empty.

Comment: okay  @JamesPaterson....... 
i put google as an example only 
mine is a different website
anyways thanking you for giving a good answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Session value in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626494/session-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

You can't access session directly in javascript because session is on server side and your javascript execute on client side.I suggest you to store your session data in some hidden filed then you can access it in your javascript like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="session_data" value="$session.sessionid" id="sessionid"/>
```

The in your javascript you can do something like this:

`var session_data = document.getElementById('sessionid').value`;